# What is Opensuse's equivalent of `apt-get source`?

Tags: apt, opensuse, zypper

In Debian I could easily download the original sources for a package with `apt-get source`. I found this very useful for learning about the software I use.

How can I do something similar in Opensuse? The closest I found is the `zyppre source-download` command according to the help text its going to download sources for every package in my system? How do I download the sources for a single package?

Output of `zypper help source-download`, for reference:

```
Download source rpms for all installed packages to a local directory.

  Command options:
-d, --directory <dir>
                     Download all source rpms to this directory.
                     Default: /var/cache/zypper/source-download
--delete             Delete extraneous source rpms in the local directory.
--no-delete          Do not delete extraneous source rpms.
--status             Don't download any source rpms,
                     but show which source rpms are missing or extraneous.
```

Comment: If you're moving from one distribution to another, keep the [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta) handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the programmers of `zypper` intended it more for *installation* of source packages than for download. I always end up going to their repository and performing a `wget` to download the source rpm:

**NOTE: this is a workaround!**

```
zypper se -s source-package-name # to determine in which repository to look
zypper lr -u # list the adresses of all repositories; so I can pick the correct one
```

now I go to that web adress look for the src.rpm; copy its adress and:

```
wget <address of src.rpm>
```

Answer (score 3):

The command `zypper source-download` is used to download source packages for the **installed** packages to a local directory.

The command `zypper si pckg_name` : to Install source packages and build their dependencies.(`source-install = si` )

The command `zypper in -D pckg_name`  to install only the source for the `pckg_name`

the command `zypper si -d pckg_name` Install only the build dependencies for the `pckg_name`

You can use the command `zypper source-install` :

To get the source package only:

```
zypper source-install -D pckg_name
```

To build dependencies only:

```
zypper source-install -d pckg_name
```

Comment: source-install in inconvenient, since it seems that packages will be downloaded to `/var/cache/zypp/packages/*/src` directories.